# NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = @{}.mutableCopy VS NSMutableDictionary * dictionary = [NSMutableDictonary new]

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I just want to know the difference between these two, I have searched but could not found anything on this, any body here can help please ?

```
NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = @{}.mutableCopy
```

VS

```
NSMutableDictionary * dictionary = [NSMutableDictonary new]
```

Comment: The first one creates a `NSDictionary` instance and send `mutableCopy` method to it, yield a `NSMutableDictionary` instance. The second one creates a `NSMutableDictionary` instance directly. I prefer the second one by the way :)

Comment: @KudoCC `@{}` doesn't construct a new `NSDictionary` instance, it reuses a singleton. But yes, the second version is more direct, and marginally (read: inconsequentially) faster.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Yes, you're right, just tested.

Comment: @KudoCC This happens to be implementation detail, but a detail you can mostly rely on. In any case, I'd recommend turning your comment into an answer; not a whole heck of a lot more to say on this subject.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Great advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one creates a `NSDictionary` instance and send `mutableCopy` method to it, yield a `NSMutableDictionary` instance.

The second one creates a `NSMutableDictionary` instance directly. I prefer the second one by the way :)

**As @Itai Ferber mentioned:**

> @{} doesn't construct a new NSDictionary instance, it reuses a singleton.

This is implementation detail but it's right, you can test using the code below:

```
NSLog(@"%p, %p", @{}, @{});
```

It will print the same address.